# Setting up a Bonjour name server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bonjour, mdns

I've been following the official documentation for DNS-SD on [setting up a Bonjour name server](http://www.dns-sd.org/serversetup.html). That is, a wide-area DNS server. The instructions seem quite old, given some of the things it refers to no longer exist (like `dnsextd` on macOS, which seems to be incorporated into *bind9* in any case).

I'm actually setting up this DNS server on a Linux installation (Raspbian), which should be possible according to that page.

> You can also use Linux, Solaris, or any other Unix-style operating system that can run the BIND name server.

Here are my relevant configuration files on the server system.

`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    forwarders {
        192.168.0.1;
        fdd4:12f8:9ad3:0:8272:15ff:fe97:6678;
    };

    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
}
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "lan." IN {
    type master;
    file "lan.zone";
};

zone "bonjour.lan." IN {
    type master;
    file "bonjour.lan.zone";
    allow-update { any; };
};
```

`/var/cache/bind/lan.zone`

```
@ IN SOA rpi.lan. hostmaster.lan. (
    1  ; serial
    8H ; refresh
    4H ; retry
    4W ; expire
    1D ; minimum
)

@             IN NS rpi.lan.
@             IN MX 10 rpi.lan.
localhost     IN A  127.0.0.1
router        IN A  192.168.0.1
rpi           IN A  192.168.0.10
```

`/var/cache/bind/bonjour.lan.zone`

```
@ IN SOA rpi.lan. hostmaster.lan. (
    1  ; serial
    3H ; refresh
    1H ; retry
    1W ; expire
    1M ; minimum
)

@ IN NS rpi.lan.

_dns-update._udp IN SRV 0 0 53 rpi.lan.

b._dns-sd._udp  IN PTR @
lb._dns-sd._udp IN PTR @
r._dns-sd._udp  IN PTR @
```

However, this set-up is failing to pick up any devices advertised on the network via Bonjour. This can be seen by running `dig bonjour.lan`.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12 <<>> bonjour.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41841
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: ebefdba02287f4bb7687ffc663fa9167695632eedfc0a265 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bonjour.lan.           IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
bonjour.lan.        60  IN  SOA rpi.lan. hostmaster.lan. 3 10800 3600 604800 60

;; Query time: 79 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.10#53(192.168.0.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb 25 22:53:27 GMT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 129
```

Any advice on how to get this working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will never "pick up" anything by itself; it is not supposed to. Wide-area DNS-SD works by the *clients* explicitly registering themselves on the server, using the DNS "UPDATE" command.

This is only supported by "Bonjour" in the sense of the specific DNS-SD implementation used by macOS (aka mDNSResponder; sometimes found installed on Windows). Its control panel allows specifying the domain and even the optional TSIG-HMAC update key. Avahi on Linux supports browsing wide-area DNS-SD domains, but not updating them.

No other DNS-SD implementations support wide-area DNS-SD at all, as far as I know; they're purely mDNS and only deal with the `local` domain. (The various mDNS-capable appliances and embedded systems have no reason to support it, and a few reasons not to.)

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying that. So just to confirm, you're saying that my RaspberryPi DNS server (bind9) won't support updating wide-area DNS-SD domains?

Comment: No, that's kind of the complete opposite of what I was saying. Bind9 is not the service that makes updates in the first place – Bind9 supports *receiving* dynamic updates, but none of your *client devices* support sending those updates.

Comment: I was under the impression at least macOS would support sending such updates... but fair enough. Anyway, that should be clear now, cheers.

Comment: Mac OS X Bonjour used to have that ability sometime around 2000s (and so did Bonjour when installed on Windows XP), but I believe they removed it at some point – didn't macOS switch over to a completely new DNS-SD implementation a few years back?

Comment: Apple are sort of working on a somewhat different unicast DNS-SD aggregator mechanism, SRP (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnssd-srp), which still uses the same concepts and underlying technologies as wide-area DNS-SD but needs a more specialized kind of DNS server. (mDNSResponder includes an SRP proxy that can bridge to/from mDNS.)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for drawing my attention to that.

Comment: And yes, seems like it's been removed, at least before macOS 13.